# COUNT the same field twice

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to COUNT the same field twice, as the current setup inputs work codes as '10', '11', '12', '13', '40', '400', '80' as completed jobs, however other works codes likes 55, 56, 57 means a job was not completed.

With the following I've managed to count the work_code table and display the amount of successful job completed, but i am struggling on how to count the same table for jobs not completed (i.e 55, 56 etc) as display that also.

Below is my code.....

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';

    $sqltran = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *, ROUND(SUM(Sales),0), ROUND(AVG(Sales),2), COUNT(Work_Code) FROM results_tbl_1 WHERE RECORD_ID BETWEEN 468100 AND 500000 AND Work_Code IN ('10', '11', '12', '13', '40', '400', '80')  GROUP BY ENG_ID ORDER BY ROUND(SUM(Sales),0) DESC ") or die(mysqli_error($con));

    $arrVal = array();

    $i=1;
    while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {

                    $name = array(
                            'num' => '<img alt="" height="16" src="./top10.png" width="16">' . $i,


                            'eng'=> $rowList['ENG_ID'],

                            'totalvisits'=> $rowList['COUNT(Work_Code)'],

                            'ajv'=> '£' . $rowList['ROUND(AVG(Sales),2)'],

                            'sales'=> '£' . $rowList['ROUND(SUM(Sales),0)'],





                        );      


                        array_push($arrVal, $name); 
        $i++;           
    }
         echo  json_encode($arrVal);        


    mysqli_close($con);
```

The data is then displayed on a bootstrap table with the below config..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 var $table = $('#table');
         $table.bootstrapTable({
              url: 'test/board.php',
              search: false,
              pagination: true,
              buttonsClass: 'primary',
              showFooter: false,
              minimumCountColumns: 2,
              columns: [{
                  field: 'num',
                  title: 'Rank',
                  sortable: false,
              },{
                  field: 'eng',
                  title: 'Engineer',
                  sortable: false,
              },{
                  field: 'totalvisits',
                  title: 'Total Jobs',
                  sortable: false,
              },{
                  field: 'ajv',
                  title: 'AJV',
                  sortable: false,
              },{


                  field: 'sales',
                  title: 'Total',
                  sortable: false,
              },  ],

         });
```

My question is how can i count the work codes 55,56 etc and display the count on the table ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why don't you run a second query with the ID's of the work codes such as 55, 56, 57?

Comment: To display how many jobs where marked at not completed to the user

Comment: I still don't see the problem. You run the first query (with 10, 11, 12) and get the `COUNT` from that result. Then you run a second query (with 55, 56, etc) and get the `COUNT` from the second result. What's wrong with that? The only thing that changes is the ID's in the `IN` condition - obviously that affects the count/results. But that's what you want.

Comment: Do you want to have count of jobs for each kind of code? For that you may want to group by job code

Answer (score 1):

Create two new arrays, one for job codes that indicate completion, another for job codes that indication incomplete. Also, don't try to do the count in your query in this case.

Then, as you're looping through your results, test `$row['Work_Code'] against the arrays using`array_search()`. You'll also need two variables to store the counts.

It would look something like this:

```
$completedJobs = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$incompleteJobs = array(7,8,9,10,11);
$completeTotal = 0;
$incompleteTotal = 0;
$i=1;
    while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sqltran)) {
      //I've stripped out what is not relevant to my example
      if(array_search($rowList['Work_Code'], $completedJobs) {
           $completeTotal++;                        
     }
     if(array_search($rowList['Work_code'],$incompleteJobs){
           $incompleteTotal++;
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but how can i display the response on my table ? - i have updated the question above with the code i am using to display it on my table.

Comment: One way would be to include the counts as values in hidden inputs when you render the page.

`echo "<input type='hidden' id='completeTotal' value = '" . $completeTotal . "'>";

Then grab the value of that in jQuery:

Comment: When you do `json_encode($arrVal);` that has the values in that have come from the database. So as long as they are in separate array keys `$arrVal['num_complete_jobs']` and `$arrVal['num_incomplete_jobs']` you should still be able to reference them in your ajax

Answer (score 0):

Just run 2 separate queries, with different values in the `IN` clause:

Completed jobs:

```
<?php 
require 'db.php';

$sql_complete = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *, ROUND(SUM(Sales),0), ROUND(AVG(Sales),2), COUNT(Work_Code) FROM results_tbl_1 WHERE RECORD_ID BETWEEN 468100 AND 500000 AND Work_Code IN ('10', '11', '12', '13', '40', '400', '80')  GROUP BY ENG_ID ORDER BY ROUND(SUM(Sales),0) DESC ") or die(mysqli_error($con));

while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_complete)) {
    // Outputs the number of completed jobs:
    echo $rowList['COUNT(Work_Code)'];
}
?>
```

Incomplete jobs:

```
<?php 

$sql_incomplete = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *, ROUND(SUM(Sales),0), ROUND(AVG(Sales),2), COUNT(Work_Code) FROM results_tbl_1 WHERE RECORD_ID BETWEEN 468100 AND 500000 AND Work_Code IN ('55', '56', '57' )  GROUP BY ENG_ID ORDER BY ROUND(SUM(Sales),0) DESC ") or die(mysqli_error($con));

while ($rowList = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_incomplete)) {
    // Outputs the number of incomplete jobs:
    echo $rowList['COUNT(Work_Code)'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but how can i display the response on my table ? - i have updated the question above with the code i am using to display it on my table.

Answer (score 0):

With assumption that **all** codes that are not in "completed jobs" codes list are incomplete, the query could be as simple as this:

```
SELECT *, ROUND(SUM(IF(complete, Sales, null)),0), ROUND(AVG(IF(complete, Sales, null)),2), COUNT(IF(complete, 1, null)), COUNT(IF(complete, null, 1)) 
FROM ( SELECT *, Work_Code IN ('10', '11', '12', '13', '40', '400', '80') as complete
  FROM results_tbl_1 
  ) separated
WHERE RECORD_ID BETWEEN 468100 AND 500000 
GROUP BY ENG_ID 
ORDER BY ROUND(SUM(Sales),0) DESC
```

A few things not related to the question:

- never do `SELECT *,` in aggregated queries
- use aliases to the aggregated columns

So the better version of the query is:

```
SELECT 
  ENG_ID, 
  ROUND(SUM(IF(complete, Sales, null)),0) as Total_sales_complete, 
  ROUND(AVG(IF(complete, Sales, null)),2) as Average_sales_complete, 
  COUNT(IF(complete, 1, null)) as Count_complete, 
  COUNT(IF(complete, null, 1)) as Count_incomplete
FROM ( SELECT *, Work_Code IN ('10', '11', '12', '13', '40', '400', '80') as complete
  FROM results_tbl_1 
  ) separated
WHERE RECORD_ID BETWEEN 468100 AND 500000 
GROUP BY ENG_ID 
ORDER BY Total_sales_complete DESC
```

**EDIT:**

The only changes in php code is to use aliases:

```
$name = array(
 'num' => '<img alt="" height="16" src="./top10.png" width="16">' . $i,
 'eng'=> $rowList['ENG_ID'],
 'totalvisits'=> $rowList['Count_complete'],
 'ajv'=> '£' . $rowList['Total_sales_complete'],
 'sales'=> '£' . $rowList['Average_sales_complete'],

 'theSecondCount'=> $rowList['Count_incomplete'],
);
```

And on javascript side add the extra column:

```
          {
              field: 'theSecondCount',
              title: 'Incomplete Jobs',
              sortable: false,
          }
```

As a side note, the title "Total Jobs" is a bit misleading, as it shows count for **complete** jobs, and the word "Total" implies all jobs.

Comment: Thanks for this, but how can i display the response on my table ? - i have updated the question above with the code i am using to display it on my table.

Comment: updated the answer, but honestly, the javascript "how can i display the response" part was added after I posted my answer. It  shows absolute lack of research efforts and violates Stackoverflow policy of not combining multiple questions into one. Please avoid it in the future.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you want to use UNION for two SELECT's with corresponding work codes.

Answer (score -2):

I might be missing the obvious but why not include the codes for not completed in the "work_code in" clause?

Comment: Because that's counting the work codes 10,11 etc that mean jobs completed, the other work codes 55, 56 etc mean jobs not completed so i want to display the amount of jobs not completed aswell as jobs completed.